# Llamamos una o varias veces al AlarmManager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

Quiero desarrollar un sistema de recordatorios en Android, y he visto que lo mejor sería utilizar AlarmManager.

Mi desarrollo ha quedado así:

Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), ReminderBroadcast.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 0,intent,0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

```
        if (frecuenciaSeleccionada == 1 || frecuenciaSeleccionada == 2|| frecuenciaSeleccionada == 3) {
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, horaAlarma, 24*60*60*1000, pendingIntent);
        }else if(frecuenciaSeleccionada==4){
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, horaAlarma, 48*60*60*1000, pendingIntent);
        }else if(frecuenciaSeleccionada==5){
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, horaAlarma, 72*60*60*1000, pendingIntent);
        }
```

En teoría lo que quiero realizar es que el sistema guarda en el sistema una serie de recordatorios, en los que en una fecha señalada y una hora fijada por el usuario, por cada registro, se genere una alarma distinta. Entonces este código que os he pasado estaría dentro del método altaRegistro, para que cada vez que hago un registro..en teoría registre una nueva alarma.

Pienso que haciendo esto se solaparía la alarma, quedando activa solo la última que guarde..Es así? Cómo puedo hacer para que el sistema me guarde varias alarmas en el sistema en función de una fecha y una hora dada?

Comment: estas usando una base de datos para guardar las fechas/horas ??

Comment: Si, ahora por fin ya consigo borrar notificaciones. Y para ello me he dado cuenta que con guardar en una bbdd el identificador de la notificación que mandamos cuando se crea.. Ya me les borra (al menos lo probé con una alarma y funcionó). Tengo que probar cuando eliminó otra alarma aleatoria.